# Kwin effects worked 100% on kubuntu 12.04 but i cant get them all to work on 14.04

Tags: compiz, kde, effects, kwin, vmware-fusion

My VMware fusion 6.0.3 VM running kubuntu 12.04 LTS worked great when using all kwin effects, but I had to use a workaround.

I put this following workaround text at the end of the 12.04 /etc/profile file to make all effects work.

```
KWIN_COMPOSE=O2 kwin --graphicssystem raster --replace &".
```

On 14.04 LTS, I get a message that says 30 effects do not load after I put my work around in place and try every combination of xrender and opengl. Is there a new workaround since my old one doesn't work? The Opening new windows in the center of the PC screen kwin effect is working on 14.04, so I guess some effects do work.

Comment: old 12.04 worked on fusion with workaround. new 14.04 does not.

Comment: thank you belacqua. changed title and edited question as well.